# How can i get j2store order details in my custom component view by order id?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

How can i get Order detail by Order id in j2store Component for joomla?
I am using custom component and i need to use j2store order in my component custom view.

I have tried this code to get order :
`$order = F0FModel::getTmpInstance('Orders', 'J2StoreModel')->initOrder($j2store_order_id)->getOrder();`

Comment: Please ask all Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.